# InDesign: How to place multiple XML elements into a single Text Field

Tags: javascript, xml, scripting, textfield, adobe-indesign

InDesign Scripting Javascript

I would like to place multiple XML Elements into a single Text Field.

Unfortunately, placeXML( using ) only takes Story, PageItem, Graphic, Movie or Sound.

I thought perhaps I could create a single XML element with two children using transformations, then tag the text field to have the tags of the children and place the parent, but this hasn't worked for me either.

Any ideas?